# php array remove double quotes

Tags: php, arrays

i am trying to parse an array and to remove the double quotes

```
<?php
include('../db_connect/sql.php');
$tmps = array();
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT temp FROM temperatures WHERE sensor_id='28-000005fd5279' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3");
    $query->execute();
$result = $query -> fetchAll();
foreach( $result as $row ) {
array_push($tmps,$row[0]);
}
echo json_encode($tmps);
?>
```

the result for me is ["31.375","30.687","29.5"]
but i need it in the following format [31.375,30.687,29.5]

i have tryed with

```
 $array_final = json_encode($array_json);
    $array_final = preg_replace('/"([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*)":/','$1:',$array_final);
    echo $array_final;
```

but it's not working for me :(

Comment: `array_push($tmps, (float) $row[0]);`

Comment: As @MarkBaker said, you need to cast it as a Float so that the encoding does not treat it as a String.

Comment: Thanks sir, i forgot about float values. thanks a lot